# Can't execute shell scripts

Tags: pantheon-terminal, bash, shell

I'm running elementary OS Freya on a HP Notebook.
I downloaded the game "Faster than Light" and the launcher is a shellscript. Even with the `+x` permssion I get `"permission denied"` messages. I don't know how to solve this.

Here is the complete output

```
ola@piteco-elementaryos:~/tralhas/jogos/FTL$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 6 ola ola  4096 Abr 20  2013 data
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ola ola    74 Abr 20  2013 FTL
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ola ola 12225 Abr 20  2013 FTL_README.html
ola@piteco-elementaryos:~/tralhas/jogos/FTL$ ./FTL
bash: ./FTL: Permission denied
ola@piteco-elementaryos:~/tralhas/jogos/FTL$ sudo su
root@piteco-elementaryos:/home/ola/tralhas/jogos/FTL# ./FTL
bash: ./FTL: Permission denied
```

The tralhas filesystem is mounted with exec option:

```
ola@piteco-elementaryos:~$ grep "tralhas" /etc/fstab
#HD tralhas
/dev/sda4 /home/ola/tralhas ext4 auto,exec,rw,user 0 0
```

Thanks for any help wih this situation :D

[EDIT]
Just copied the folder into my home folder and the script runned just fine:

```
ola@piteco-elementaryos:~/FTL$ ./FTL 
Loading Arch = amd64
No settings file found! 
Initializing Crash Catcher...
Initializing Video
Video Initialized
Opengl version = 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
Starting audio library...
Audio Initialized!
Resource Preload: 19.284
Loading text....
Initializing animations...
Animations Initialized!
Loading Ship Blueprints....
Blueprints Loaded!
Initializing Sound Data....
Generating world...
Loading achievements...
Loading score file...
Running Game!
```

Yet I can't run the one at the `tralhas` filesystem.

Comment: Is it ntfs partition ?

Comment: No. As you can see in the /etc/fstab, it is ext4 partition

Answer (score 1):

Place the exec option after the user option, or your drive will still be mounted as noexec, because user option implies noexec, nosuid, and nodev.